# How to enable remote access in my local application - IIS Windows 10

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7.5

I have an application in my machine, and i can access it by localhost/myapplication normally, but I'm making a integration with a payment website, this website needs an url to send me notifications about the transaction status, I know if I had put my application online, it would access my notification url, but i need to debug it locally. There is a way to enable access to my application even if staying in my machine?
I did lots of researchs of how to put IIS online but it just found threads that explain how do it only in same network that i am.
I am using windows 10 and IIS, builded on asp.net mvc and C#

Comment: It depends where your application runs and which access you have to the server running IIS. There is a possibility for remote debugging [Remote Debugging ASP.NET on a Remote IIS Computer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/mt621540.aspx).

Comment: @H.G.Sandhagen It might solve the problem! Thanks

Comment: You can try to set a static IP publicly accessible from your PC, that way your website hosted in local IIS can be accessed outside through static IP and that payment website can send notification to your locally hosted website.

Answer (score 0):

The approach I would take at present is to download our free VS Extension called Conveyor https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a429dbb7-a982-4541-b401-934375c02c0f?redir=0

It allows machines off localhost to connect to your IIS Express apps.  At present that's not quite enough because you also need to connect to it over the internet.  We're actually working on the feature to support that.

If you have the ability to forward external ports to your machine, then you could do that.  On a home network for example that's simply going in to your router, and setting up an arbitrary port to forward to your computer, so lets say forward port 50000 to your machine's IP and give it the port that Conveyor runs on (typically 45455).

Then you can use your network's public IP and port 50000 to connect to your app.

Eg. on a home network your router might have the public IP 96.97.98.0 so you would use the address https://96.97.98.0:50000 from the payment system.

Comment: I've done what you said, I setup a port in my router which is this case is a tp-link, I've added incoming rules in the firewall but it is not working yet,  I guess that just a little thing should be wrong in what i'm doing.

Comment: @RodrigodeFarias Is Conveyor running, does it show you a URL to use for inside your LAN?  It should give a URL like http://<your internal IP>:<port> (where port is usually 45455).  When you hit the public IP based URL, what are you getting in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with IIS Express. I needed to access a local website from a virtual machine attached to my home network.

By default IIS Express listens to TCPv6 port. So I had to forward it to some TCPv4 port on my network interface.

For example, if your website runs at`localhost:60000` and you want it to be accessible at `192.168.1.50:3000` you can do the following in administrative console or powershell under admin:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> netsh
netsh>interface
netsh interface>portproxy
netsh interface portproxy>add v4tov6 listenport=3000 connectaddress=[::1] connectport=60000
```

Now when you open http://localhost:3000/ or http://192.168.1.50:3000/ you should see your website that runs on `60000` port.

Here is a blog post on this - http://programmingflow.com/2017/02/25/iis-express-on-external-ip.html

The solution is permanent, you don't need to repeat the configuration after restart, also it does not require any 3rd party software or changing your website's configuration.

The only thing that might require some more tweaking is making sure your requests contain proper `Host` HTTP-header in them, otherwise IIS Express might reject them with `400 Bad request` error.

Comment: _Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline._